# Blurry text when rotating with webkit-transform in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, rotation, webkit

I rotate an element using `-webkit-transform: rotate()`, but the problem is that this does not work properly in Google Chrome. It looks like smooth font in Photoshop.

I've added `translate3d()` but that doesn't work.

Could you tell me if this is normal behavior or is there a way to solve this problem?

```css
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3.5deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3.5deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3.5deg);  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: rotate(-3.5deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
  transform: rotate(-3.5deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */

  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;    
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.inverse {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3.5deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-transform: rotate(3.5deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
  -ms-transform: rotate(3.5deg);  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: rotate(3.5deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
  transform: rotate(3.5deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */

  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved!

The problem wasn't Google Chrome, but the LayerSlider.
With `z-index` and position absolute I resolved this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. where did you add z-index and position absolute?